# How can I operate the overlaid loop correctly on Android?

Tags: android, loops, button, while-loop

I want to make an application to find the ideal type of tournament. The code below is a function that starts when you press the Start button. 'choice1' and 'choice2' are boolean that becomes true when each image button is pressed. The problem is that 'round' and 'stage' don't move on. I'm still looking for a way, but I can't solve it. Help me, please.

```
public class GirlWorldCup extends Activity {
    boolean choice1;
    boolean choice2;

    Button start;
    ImageButton image1, image2;
    TextView txt1, txt2;
    ArrayList<Integer> photoList;
    ArrayList<Integer> photoList1;
    ArrayList<String> nameList;
    ArrayList<String> nameList1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.girl);
        int[] photos= {R.drawable.blackpink_jenny, R.drawable.cho_boa,R.drawable.han_hyojoo,R.drawable.han_jimin,
                R.drawable.han_sohee,R.drawable.hyeri,R.drawable.jeon_jihyeon, R.drawable.iu};
        photoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i : photos) {
            photoList.add(i);
        }
        photoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] names ={"블랙핑크 제니","조보아","한효주","한지민","한소희","혜리","전지현", "아이유"};
        nameList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(names));
        nameList1 = new ArrayList<>();


        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        TextView roundTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.roundTxt);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                worldCup();
            }
        });
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                choice1 = true;
                worldCup();
            }
        });
        image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                choice2 = true;
                worldCup();
            }
        });
    }
    public void worldCup(){
        int round = 8;
        outerloop: //label the loop
        while(true) {
            if (round == 1) {
                image1.setImageResource(photoList.get(0));
                txt1.setText("당신의 최종 이상형입니다.");
                break;
            }
            int stage = 0;
            while(true) {
                if (stage == round) {
                    photoList.clear();
                    photoList = photoList1;
                    photoList1.clear();

                    nameList.clear();
                    nameList = nameList1;
                    nameList1.clear();
                    break outerloop; //break it
                }
                image1.setImageResource(photoList.get(stage));
                image2.setImageResource(photoList.get(stage + 1));
                txt1.setText(nameList.get(stage));
                txt2.setText(nameList.get(stage + 1));
                if (choice1) {
                    photoList1.add(photoList.get(stage+1));
                    nameList1.add(nameList.get(stage+1));
                    choice1 = false;
                    stage = stage + 2;
                    continue;
                } else if (choice2) {
                    photoList1.add(photoList.get(stage));
                    nameList1.add(nameList.get(stage));
                    choice2 = false;
                    stage = stage + 2;
                    continue;
                }
                round = round / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will give you an ANR.

Comment: Then how can I solve it?

Comment: You can't do infinite loops on main thread. I suggest you remove logic code from activity and follow a more clean architecture: https://medium.com/@pavan.careers5208/detailed-guide-on-android-clean-architecture-9eab262a9011